# Why is Safari rendering my TM symbol as â„¢?

Tags: html, angular, browser, utf-8, safari

I was sent an HTML file to evaluate. The first line looks like:

```
<h1>myCompanyName<sup>™</sup></h1>
```

Which renders as

## myCompanyName<sup>™</sup>

.

When I open this file in Chrome or Firefox, the trademark symbol renders fine. However, in Safari, it renders like:

## myCompanyName<sup>â„¢</sup>

.

Why is Safari interpreting this small 'TM' as â„¢ , and what can I do to avoid this?

Interestingly, if I paste this same code into a Visual Studio Code web app and serve it, it renders properly on all browsers regardless. Only when opening the HTML file on its own via 'open with browser' does it mess up in Safari.

Answer (score 3):

The encoding isn't declared correctly.  A UTF-8-encoded `™` decoded as Windows-1252 displays as `â„¢`.

A proof using Python:

```py
>>> print('™'.encode('utf8').decode('windows-1252'))
â„¢
```

Try, as a minimum:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"><h1>myCompanyName<sup>™</sup></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. This HTML is going to be pulled into an Angular web app via an Asynchronous GET request when a particular page is visited. So in our index.html file we already have a charset="utf-8" attribute. I'm wondering now if that utf-8 will take effect when html is pulled in after the fact....perhaps the solution here is to ensure that the file encoding is changed to utf-8?

Comment: @KyleVassella if you see `â„¢` your file *was* encoded in UTF8, just decoded incorrectly.  Was `meta charset` On that particular page?